Setting priority fee for deploy solana-cli: '--with-compute-unit-price' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context
According to this post I am trying to set higher fee to make a successful deploy
solana program deploy ./target/deploy/prog.so --with-compute-unit-price 200000

But it doesn't work
error: Found argument '--with-compute-unit-price' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context

What is the right flag to set higher fees for the deploy command

My version was outdated (1.18.2)
solana-install update

will bring you to 1.18.9
--with-compute-unit-price 200000

is working fine there
